# Is it possible to reset CSS within an HTML file?

Tags: html, css

If I link a cascading stylesheet in my code with:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
```

and within my CSS file I have

```
a:link, a:visited {
    display: block;
    width: 120px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #1947D1;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 4px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
a:hover, a:active {
    background-color:#0029A3;
}
```

it all works fine, until I have to have a link that is formatted differently. Is it possible to easily reset the style completely or for one element in the middle of an HTML file? Or must I manually reset each aspect?  I have tried doing

```
<style></style>
```

and

```
<a style="" href="projects.html">Projects</a>
```

but neither reset the style. Is this not possible, or am I just missing something obvious?

Comment: Why don't you give that element a class of its own and the pseudo-class?

Comment: Any reason you are not using a class for the links? Then you could do a.class and it would only apply to the links that you have assigned the class.

Comment: @JoePacker That would work, thanks!  I knew I would be missing something pretty obvious.

Comment: thats what i wrote in my answer :)

Answer (score 2):

if I understand correctly you are looking to style the `A` link to projects in a different way that the rest of the main `A` links. right?

if so here it is:

```
<a class="some-class" href="projects.html">Projects</a>

.some-class {
background-color:red /* whatever you want here. */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a class name to your CSS and to your  tag, and this will work fine.

```
a.class_name:link, a.class_name:visited {
    display: block;
    width: 120px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #1947D1;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 4px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transformation: uppercase;
}
a.class_name:hover, a.class_name:active {
    background-color:#0029A3;
}

<a class="class_name" href="projects.html">Projects</a>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's pretty much what I ended up doing, although I used "a:link.classname" rather than "a.classname:link"